# Data Frame to Excel - AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, dataframe, attributeerror, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to write a data frame to an Excel file. This has worked for me in the past, but this time, it's giving me an `AttributeError`.

**The Code**

I have a data frame called `data` that looks like this:
[image: data frame called <code>data</code>]

I put it into this code:

```
# To find tf-idf values
textVal = data.text.values.astype('str')
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(textVal)
X = vectorizer.transform (textVal).toarray()
names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
tfidf_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = names)

# To print TF-IDF
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('tfidf_test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
tfidf_dataframe.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
print("complete")
```

The `tfidf_dataframe` looks like this:

[image: tfidf_dataframe image]

**The Error Log**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-9ebe0a5d13a5> in <module>
     13 
     14 # To print TF-IDF
---> 15 tfidf_dataframe.to_excel(writer)
     16 
     17 # To print sentiment analysis

c:\users\matay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes)
   2162         from pandas.io.formats.excel import ExcelFormatter
   2163 
-> 2164         formatter = ExcelFormatter(
   2165             df,
   2166             na_rep=na_rep,

c:\users\matay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py in __init__(self, df, na_rep, float_format, cols, header, index, index_label, merge_cells, inf_rep, style_converter)
    403             self.df = df.reindex(columns=cols)
    404 
--> 405         self.columns = self.df.columns
    406         self.float_format = float_format
    407         self.index = index

c:\users\matay\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5268             or name in self._accessors
   5269         ):
-> 5270             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5271         else:
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Any ideas on why I get this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're getting this from what you're running? Your traceback seems to imply it's not.

```
     14 # To print TF-IDF
---> 15 tfidf_dataframe.to_excel(writer)
     16 
     17 # To print sentiment analysis
```

```
# To print TF-IDF
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('tfidf_test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
tfidf_dataframe.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
print("complete")
```

I believe the default engine is already `xlsxwriter`, so you could also just do `tfidf_dataframe.to_excel('tfidf_test.xlsx')`

One of my hunches might be that if this code lives in a module, you're actively developing it and you didn't re-import it into your Jupyter environment.

If that's the case, try:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module)
```

Where module is the name of the module where your code resides.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not quite sure what a module is. I am working in Jupyter, though. How do I find out if it's in a module?

Comment: UPDATE: I decided to restart Jupyter, and now I'm getting a new error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: This often happens when you are using local libraries or run cells out of order. It's hard to tell without the exact code. Looks like you're trying to do some kind of `df.data` at some point, which is not a valid attribute.

Comment: I'm not calling a kind of `df.data` as far as I can tell. Do you think you could look at my code [here](https://github.com/MollyATaylor/excel-writer-help) and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for all your help, by the way. I'm doing this whole project without knowing anyone who can help me, so I greatly appreciate you taking your time for me.